# How to parse in android application arraylist from php webservice

Tags: android, web-services, soap, xml-parsing

```
public static UserFriendListContainer getFriendList(SoapObject wizardobject)//TESTED
    {
        UserFriendListContainer container= new UserFriendListContainer();


        List<UserFriendListModel> list= new ArrayList();    

        String currobj= wizardobject.getProperty("FriendListResult").toString();

        Log.v("CurrentObjet+++++++",currobj.toString());




        container.setParserResult(currobj);



        SoapObject result = (SoapObject)wizardobject;
        for(int i=0;i<result.getPropertyCount();i++)
        {

                SoapObject object = (SoapObject)wizardobject.getProperty(i);//here it is break

Log.v("result:::::",result.toString());
                Log.v("obj:::::",object.toString());
                Log.v("friendID",object.getProperty("friendid").toString());
                String friendID=object.getProperty("friendid").toString();

                Log.v("friendname",object.getProperty("friendname").toString());
                String friendname=object.getProperty("friendname").toString();

                Log.v("lastaction",object.getProperty("lastaction").toString());
                String lastaction=object.getProperty("lastaction").toString();

                Log.v("friendphoto",object.getProperty("friendphoto").toString());
                String friendphoto=object.getProperty("friendphoto").toString();

                UserFriendListModel model=new UserFriendListModel();
                model.setfriendID(friendID);
                model.setfriendName(friendname);
                model.setfriendPhoto(friendphoto);
                model.setLastAction(lastaction);

                list.add(model);
            }
            container.setList(list);

        return container;
    }

}

-----
<message name="FriendListRequest"/>
<message name="FriendListResponse">
<part name="FriendListResult" type="tns:FirendListArray"/>
</message>
```

my xml part from webservice is that one.Im trying to access my friendlist by parsing.I couldnt understand ..when im debugging it broke in "SoapObject object = (SoapObject)wizardobject.getProperty(i)"..I want to know how can i parse one list that i take from webservice??Thank you for your help in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static UserFriendListContainer getfriendlist(SoapObject wizardobject) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

        UserFriendListContainer container= new UserFriendListContainer();
        UserFriendListModel model = new UserFriendListModel();

         List<UserFriendListModel> list= null;
          list=new ArrayList<UserFriendListModel>();
        Vector vector = (Vector) wizardobject.getProperty("FriendListResult");

          Log.v("vector+++++++",vector.toString());
          System.out.println("vectorsize+++++++"+vector.size());

          int count=vector.size();


          for (int i = 0; i <count; ++i) { 

        SoapObject test=(SoapObject)vector.get(i);


          Log.v("test+++++++",test.toString());  

               Log.v("friendid",test.getProperty("friendid").toString());
                String friendID=test.getProperty("friendid").toString();

                Log.v("friendname",test.getProperty("friendname").toString());
                String friendname=test.getProperty("friendname").toString();

                Log.v("lastaction",test.getProperty("lastaction").toString());
                String lastaction=test.getProperty("lastaction").toString();

                Log.v("friendphoto",test.getProperty("friendphoto").toString());
                String friendphoto=test.getProperty("friendphoto").toString();

                model.setfriendID(friendID);
                model.setfriendName(friendname);
                model.setfriendPhoto(friendphoto);
                model.setLastAction(lastaction);

                list.add(model);
            }
            container.setList(list);
            System.out.println("List==="+list);


         return container;
    }
```

Hi guys,
After so many effort i have found my answer..I can parse my array with above code..Thank u for interest..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that **wizardobject.getProperty(i)**

returns a SoapObject?? I would try with a String or just debug it without doing the casting and see what kind of object it is.

Check this -> [SoapObject documentation](http://ksoap.objectweb.org/software/documentation/api/org/ksoap/SoapObject.html)

By the way it's handier if you post the error stack trace.

Comment: 06-03 11:49:17.187: V/RESPONSE OF getFriendList:(275): FriendListResponse{FriendListResult=[FirendList{friendid=1; friendphoto=profile1.jpg; friendname=Onur Enis Bozdemir; lastaction=Giriş Yaptı - (5 dk önce); }, FirendList{friendid=3; friendphoto=profile5.jpg; friendname=test test; lastaction=Giriş Yaptı - (5 dk önce); }]; }
06-03 11:49:31.159: D/SntpClient(58): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
  in my log cat I have these results..I cant take my list