# Get a List of array from webservice in android

Tags: php, android, web-services, android-ksoap2

I have an array of object coming from a PHP web service which has contents like :

```
anyType[
objectname1{element1=1234567890; element2=test; element3=1110; element3=72.824043; },
objectname1{element1=11090999; element2=test; element3=2292; element3=72.824043; }]
```

I am using ksoap2 to get the webservice data in my android application.

I have tried by using the [chadi cortbaoui's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1063062/chadi-cortbaoui) solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205290/android-ksoap-get-a-list-array-of-class-from-webservice) but it is giving error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Vector cannot be cast to
>   org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject

for line `SoapObject response1 = (SoapObject) response.getProperty(0);` with following code

```
envelope.encodingStyle = "UTF-8";
httpTransport.debug = true;
httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
response =  (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
SoapObject response1 = (SoapObject) response.getProperty(0);
```

I have tried by using the `SoapPrimitive` instead of `SoapObject` also i have tried by using the `envelope.getResponse()` in place of `envelope.bodyIn` but it does not work it throws the same error.

Comment: @SamirMangroliya : how is that related ? your post is about json. This question is not.

Comment: @SamirMangroliya how should i use you post in my case ? can you please help me out if i can use post in my problem ? I have tried using the code in your post but it throws an error for the Unterminated array at character 12 i.e "=" sign in my string array ?

Comment: @SamirMangroliya i solved my problem also your link did not helped as what i am geeting as a response was not a JSON string.anyways thanks for your help.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using the following code with the help of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807150/how-to-parse-in-android-application-arraylist-from-php-webservice)

```
httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
response =  (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
Vector<?> responseVector = (Vector<?>) response.getProperty(0);//store the response object values in a Vector(It solved the vector error which i was getting

int count=responseVector.size();

for (int i = 0; i <count; ++i) { //for loop for the array of the result    
SoapObject test=(SoapObject)responseVector.get(i);
String value1 = test.getProperty("value1").toString();//get Your values from the soap object
String value2 = test.getProperty("value2").toString();
String value3 = test.getProperty("value3").toString();
String value4 = test.getProperty("value4").toString();
  /*thats it now add the received values to your list using the for loop*/
}
```

thanks.